# Writing a simple jquery/javascript library how to start inti functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, initialization

I'm writing a simple jquery library of all of the functions I use a lot such and email validation etc.. How to run inti document not working.

```
var scriptName = {

init: function() {

alert('working');
  },

 }
  //This is not working!!!!
 $( document ).ready(function() {
  init();
 });
```

Comment: seems like your `ready` should fire `init`, no? Otherwise I have absolutely no idea what you're asking.

Comment: Why don't you use `$( obj )` and what is suddenly `$obj.val();`?

Comment: Basically how to fire/run the functions?

Comment: This is just a sample so $obj.val(); will be updated or changed. Just trying to run the functions on init. Do I use document ready?

Comment: Have you tried `scriptName.init()`?

Comment: `init` is a property (method) of the `scriptName` object not a global method, so you need to treat it that way. Therefore you can call it by simply using `scriptName.init()`.

Comment: Thanks bros that's what I was looking for scriptName.init()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it with `scriptName.init();`

Your code: http://jsfiddle.net/KTeLR/

Answer (score 0):

```
var scriptName = {
    init: function() {
        alert('working');
    }
};

//This is working!!!!
$(document).ready(function() {
    scriptName.init();
});
```